# PDO closeCursor() after exec

Tags: php, pdo

I have custom ORM system wich is based on mysql_ functions now I am rewriting it for PDO but I have problem with "general error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active"

here is code that handles SQL queries(SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE etc.) with some debugin echoes:

```
public function query($sql,$mode='exec'){

    echo 'Tring Query:'.$sql.'<br>in mode '.$mode.'<br>';
    if($mode=='select'){
        echo 'select query inside if<br>';
        try {
        $result=$this->pdo->query($query);
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            //error handle
            log::writeLogEntry('PDO error - '.$ex->getMessage());
            return FALSE;
        }   
    }
    else{
        echo 'other query inside else<br>';
        $this->pdo->exec($sql);
        //here I need to close cursor 
        return TRUE;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I know that I need to close cursor to be able to issue next query where the coment is however I have no idea how I tried to store the call to variable but it wont crate apropriate PDO object to call closeCursor() on it. I supose I shuld prepare it some how to be able to close cursor after exec but what I devised didnt work eighter.

Comment: whole ORM can be found in its curent state on
https://github.com/Erwin32/Abstract-DB-layer-and-loging/tree/develop

Comment: you mean you want to know how to close cursor? `$this->closeCursor();`